# Problem with uploading images only on the server? Laravel + Vue

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

Everything works in the localhost, but when the project goes to the server, it does not write the path of the image into the database table, and the upload of the new product does not work. I don't know the reason why I have to write permissions on the server. Look at my code in Laravel:

```
public function uploadImage($car, $images)
{
    $fileName = Carbon::now()->timestamp . $images->getClientOriginalName();
    $path = $images->move(public_path('public/images'), $fileName);
    if (!$path) {
        return response()->json(['message' => 'An error has accured'], 500);
    }
    $carImage = new CarImages ([
        'path' => 'public/images/' . $fileName
    ]);

    $car->images()->save($carImage);

    return $carImage;
}
```

This should be writing a path to the database but it does not work.
The error which I got: " message: "Server Error" " in the network.

> Error in console: 500 (Internal Server Error) and Uncaught (in
>   promise) Error: Error: Request failed with status code 500.

This is the function which handles images on front:

```
   onFileChange(event) {
    this.picture = event.target.files[0];
    // console.log(this.picture);
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    this.imgSrc = URL.createObjectURL(this.picture);
  },
```

If you want the entire code I can post that but I think the problem is in the path, but I am not really sure what happened to this...

Last error storage/logs ->

> [2019-04-19 10:20:43] production.ERROR: No application encryption key
>   has been specified. {"exception":"[object] (RuntimeException(code: 0):
>   No application encryption key has been specified. at
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\mvp-cars-export\api\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Encryption\EncryptionServiceProvider.php:44)
>   [stacktrace]

But I don't know what this error is.

Comment: which field are you sending in server picture or imgSrc?

Comment: okay then run `php artisan key:generate` command in server.

Comment: fd.append('picture', this.picture);
php artisan key:generate why?

Comment: because you get error in log file like No application encryption key has been specified

Comment: does it make sense?

Comment: Okay problem is on server...
One server work all perfectly
Another server return error....
Any permission or anythink but i am not system admin..

Comment: First of all , error specified on log is related to encryption key which can be solve by `php artisan key:generate` and  cache clear command , but this error will be on all pages on server not only specific to image upload . you can enable debug for while and get actual error . Sometime its related to php post maxsize upload issue

Comment: Problem was be in any permission on server. I am not sys admin and I really don't know what was be problem. Thanks for try to help me